# google ortools vrp set break fails

Tags: or-tools

I modified the original vrptw.py sample and want to set break for couple vehicles/routes.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2


def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['time_matrix'] = [
        [0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3, 6, 2, 3, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 9, 7],
        [6, 0, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4, 8, 8, 13, 7, 5, 8, 12, 10, 14],
        [9, 8, 0, 11, 10, 6, 3, 9, 5, 8, 4, 15, 14, 13, 9, 18, 9],
        [8, 3, 11, 0, 1, 7, 10, 6, 10, 10, 14, 6, 7, 9, 14, 6, 16],
        [7, 2, 10, 1, 0, 6, 9, 4, 8, 9, 13, 4, 6, 8, 12, 8, 14],
        [3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 7, 9, 7, 7, 6, 12, 8],
        [6, 8, 3, 10, 9, 2, 0, 6, 2, 5, 4, 12, 10, 10, 6, 15, 5],
        [2, 4, 9, 6, 4, 3, 6, 0, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 10],
        [3, 8, 5, 10, 8, 2, 2, 4, 0, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 3, 13, 6],
        [2, 8, 8, 10, 9, 2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 5],
        [6, 13, 4, 14, 13, 7, 4, 8, 4, 4, 0, 10, 9, 8, 4, 13, 4],
        [6, 7, 15, 6, 4, 9, 12, 5, 9, 6, 10, 0, 1, 3, 7, 3, 10],
        [4, 5, 14, 7, 6, 7, 10, 4, 8, 5, 9, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 8],
        [4, 8, 13, 9, 8, 7, 10, 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6],
        [5, 12, 9, 14, 12, 6, 6, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 9, 2],
        [9, 10, 18, 6, 8, 12, 15, 8, 13, 9, 13, 3, 4, 5, 9, 0, 9],
        [7, 14, 9, 16, 14, 8, 5, 10, 6, 5, 4, 10, 8, 6, 2, 9, 0],
    ]
    import numpy as np
    # data['time_matrix'] = np.full(np.array(data['time_matrixs']).shape, fill_value=1)
    # data['time_matrix'] = np.array(data['time_matrixs'])[np.array(data['time_matrixs']) == 0] == 0
    data['time_windows'] = [
        (0, 10),  # depot
        (7, 12),  # 1
        (10, 15),  # 2
        (16, 18),  # 3
        (10, 13),  # 4
        (5, 30),  # 5
        (5, 10),  # 6
        (5, 30),  # 7
        (5, 10),  # 8
        (5, 10),  # 9
        (10, 16),  # 10
        (10, 20),  # 11
        (5, 30),  # 12
        (5, 11),  # 13
        (7, 30),  # 14
        (10, 19),  # 15
        (11, 15),  # 16
    ]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 4
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment):
    """Prints assignment on console."""
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie('Time')
    total_time = 0
    print('Breaks:')
    intervals = assignment.IntervalVarContainer()
    for i in range(intervals.Size()):
        brk = intervals.Element(i)
        if brk.PerformedValue() == 1:
            print('{}: Start({}) Duration({})'.format(
                brk.Var().Name(),
                brk.StartValue(),
                brk.DurationValue()))
        else:
            print('{}: Unperformed'.format(brk.Var().Name()))
    print()
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
            slack_var = time_dimension.SlackVar(index)
            plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2}) Slack({3},{4}) -> '.format(
                manager.IndexToNode(index), assignment.Min(time_var),
                assignment.Max(time_var), assignment.Min(slack_var), assignment.Max(slack_var))
            index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)

        plan_output += '{0} Time({1},{2})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                    assignment.Min(time_var),
                                                    assignment.Max(time_var))
        plan_output += 'Time of the route: {}min\n'.format(
            assignment.Min(time_var))
        print(plan_output)
        total_time += assignment.Min(time_var)
    print('Total time of all routes: {}min'.format(total_time))
    slack_var = time_dimension.SlackVar(int(2))
    print(slack_var.Bound())
    if slack_var.Bound():
        slack_min = assignment.Min(slack_var)
        slack_max = assignment.Max(slack_var)
    # print("assignment.Min(slack_var): ", assignment.Value(slack_var))


def main():
    """Solve the VRP with time windows."""
    data = create_data_model()
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['time_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
        if from_index == to_index: return 0
        return 1
        # from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        # to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        # return data['time_matrix'][from_node][to_node]


    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    time = 'Time'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        30*100,  # allow waiting time
        50,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time)
    time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
    # Add breaks TODO Uncomment
    node_visit_transit = {}
    for n in range(routing.Size()):
        if n >= len(data['time_windows']):
            node_visit_transit[n] = 0
        else:
            node_visit_transit[n] = 0  # int(data['demands'][n] * data['time_per_demand_unit'])

    break_intervals = {}
    # for v in xrange(data['num_vehicles']):
    for v in [0,1]:
        # vehicle_break = data['breaks'][v]
        break_intervals[v] = [
            routing.solver().FixedDurationIntervalVar(
                0, 0, 1, False, 'Break for vehicle {}'.format(v))
        ]
        time_dimension.SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle(
            break_intervals[v], v, node_visit_transit)
    # Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
        if location_idx == 0:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
        routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(index))

    # Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data['time_windows'][0][0], data['time_windows'][0][1])
        routing.AddToAssignment(time_dimension.SlackVar(index))

    for i in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.Start(i)))
        routing.AddVariableMinimizedByFinalizer(
            time_dimension.CumulVar(routing.End(i)))





    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 5
    # search_parameters.log_search = True

    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    if assignment:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note:

1. Transit time is exactly 1
2. number of vehicles: 4
3. The break is at the beging

The problem is when I set break (node_visit_transit=1) for more than 2 vehicles, it stucks. 
Could you please explain what's wrong with code and why it stuck?

P.S. When I set break for only one vehicle[ex:0 and 1], the output is as following:

```
Breaks:
Break for vehicle 0: Start(0) Duration(1)
Break for vehicle 1: Start(0) Duration(1)

Route for vehicle 0:
0 Time(1,1) Slack(0,0) -> 0 Time(2,2)
Time of the route: 2min

Route for vehicle 1:
0 Time(1,1) Slack(16,16) -> 0 Time(18,18)
Time of the route: 18min

Route for vehicle 2:
0 Time(0,0) Slack(4,6) -> 13 Time(5,7) Slack(0,2) -> 9 Time(6,8) Slack(0,2) -> 8 Time(7,9) Slack(0,2) -> 6 Time(8,10) Slack(0,2) -> 2 Time(10,11) Slack(0,1) -> 1 Time(11,12) Slack(0,1) -> 4 Time(12,13) Slack(2,3) -> 3 Time(16,16) Slack(0,0) -> 0 Time(17,17)
Time of the route: 17min

Route for vehicle 3:
0 Time(0,0) Slack(10,10) -> 16 Time(11,11) Slack(0,0) -> 15 Time(12,12) Slack(0,0) -> 14 Time(13,13) Slack(0,0) -> 12 Time(14,14) Slack(0,0) -> 11 Time(15,15) Slack(0,0) -> 10 Time(16,16) Slack(0,0) -> 7 Time(17,17) Slack(0,0) -> 5 Time(18,18) Slack(0,0) -> 0 Time(19,19)
Time of the route: 19min

Total time of all routes: 56min
False
```

Please note, The slack and time for route 2 and 3 of depot is strange

Comment: did you find the answer?I have so much trouble with ortools and can;t find the answer!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, no(. Does or tools still has such issue? in my case it was couple years ago

Comment: yes it does have this kind of problems still now

Comment: sad to hear that as it is part of google